# How to default to the bottom of a page after a form submission in html and flask?

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, default

I have a form that directs to '/prediction'.

```
<form action = '/prediction' method = 'post'>
<input type = 'number' name = 'shotsh'/>
```

I want the form to open '/prediction' at the bottom of the page rather than the top. If this is not possible, could I make the page open at the bottom directly in my Flask app where I create the url?

```
@app.route('/prediction',  methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def prediction():
...
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but your HTML is not quite valid. I suggest you use a HTML validator. For example, there should be no spaces around the `=` characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a browser jump to a specific section of the HTML page by using an URL fragment that points to an element's ID.

First, you need to add an element at the end of the page. The element type does not matter, just the ID. The value of this ID must be unique for the whole page.

```
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Then, you can point a browser to jump to that area by appending a hashtag and the ID to the URL, e.g.:

```
<form action="/prediction#bottom" method="post">
```

Not sure all browsers support this as form target, so you might need to add some JS to the page to perform the jump on load.

Comment: Thank you very much, this will work well.